# What cmd can I use to find all (text) files whose name is of some form in a directory?

Tags: bash, scripting

I would like to write a bash script that runs a .cpp program on a number of text files (I'll henceforth refer to those text files as input files). The .cpp program assumes that there is an input text file in the same directory level called "input.txt". However, the inputs I would like to run through the program are in a sub-directory and there are more than one input txt files that I would like to run through the program.

The input txt files are named using the following convention:
input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.txt, etc,...

They are placed in a folder called "myInputs" which contains text files with similar name e.g., input1.txt.Sol that I'm not interested in.

The commands I would like to have in my script should look in 'myInputs' for txt files of the form: input%.txt where % may be a number. For each file of that form, the script should print out the name of the file on a line-by-line basis. i.e., input1.txt should be on its own line, input2.txt should be on it own line.

Any tip is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the actual directory structure instead of trying to explain it. Does `find myInputs -name 'input*.txt'` do what you want?

Comment: I don't know how to "Show" you the actual directory structure without describing it, sorry. The simplest description I can come up with is this: myInputs is a directory in myProgram, which contains the .cpp executable.

Comment: find myInputs -name 'input*.txt'  is a great suggestion but it prefixes the textfiles found with myInputs/ which is not what I'm looking for. Is there some way to remove that?

Comment: Copy and paste the output of `ls` over a representative sample of the tree or draw it with ascii art or take a screenshot if you must.

Comment: ls myInput | grep 'input[0-9].txt$' seems to do the job but I'm interested in if you can use 'find' to do it :)

Comment: If all the files are in a single directory then just use a glob. `input*.txt` will match (and expand to) the filenames in that directory that match. Doing that for *only* numeric matches is more complicated and would require `find` with a regex name match.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bash command called find
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    (void)system( "find \"MyInputs\" \"input*.txt\"" );

    /* whatever comes next */

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know that much C++, but here's a snippet in C

Comment: Maybe you can write an example of use?

Comment: find "MyInputs" "input*.txt" is the rough syntax, but in a C or Cpp program you'll want to use system() or exec() to run the bash script. Then run the cpp code in the script

Comment: Not here, in your answer! Will be more valuable.